# pixel_cloud_fusion - "camera" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist

Tags: ros, yolo

I'm trying to get Autoware to send out a tracked-object list for the LGSVL Simulation. I turn on Yolo3, Euclidian Cluster detection, then pixel_cloud_fusion. When I do, it constantly states that it's looking for TF and Intrinsics data. Looking further, this seems to be a "camera_info" topic that is missing. So I made one up just trying to get it working (not sure if LGSVL has any kind of native support??). I used a bunch of 1s for the matrices and "plumb bob" for the type and matched the width/height to the published camera images. Once I send it, however, I get the error:

```
[pixel_cloud_fusion] "camera" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist
```

I have no idea what this means and the text does not appear in the Autoware software. Am I doing something wrong? Is there another topic I'm lacking?

P.S Maybe someone with 1500 rep should create an Autoware tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this might be an issue with the TF tree being incomplete.  For loopup transform to work it needs a well defined TF tree to whatever other fixed frame.  To add your camera to the TF tree you should be able to use the [static transform publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher).

Comment: I essentially had to add a "static_transform_publisher" to the tf.launch file from the autoware-data that was downloaded separate from the autoware repo and then set the Autoware Runtime Manager to use the tf.launch from the Map tab in the TF section. Thanks for the tip!
Ex:
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_to_base" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /camera 10" />